# Managing multiple dates in single column of shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, date

I have data example an organizations,

which consists sl.no, name of organization, facility type, latitude, longitude starting date of facility.My problem is for particular facility i had two or more starting dates, now i want to store  those multiple dates in single file, how is it possible?
my data is now in excel, i want to make shape file now..

Answer (score 5):

You can use a One-to-many relationship from a shapefile ("one") to a table ("many").

Store all data that is unique for each facility in a shapefile:
facility-id, Geometry, type, lat, log, ...

Store data with one or more values for each facility in a second table e.g. *.dbf (not in a shape file!):
facility-id, start-date, ...

Relate (not join!) the shapefile and the table. Use facility-id as keyfield.

You can find more information in [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_joining_and_relating_tables/005s0000002n000000/).